# Sitecore context in the initialize pipeline

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sitecore

The end target is to `EnableCors` and read the allowed domain from Sitecore.
But in the initialize pipeline the Sitecore context is null and that's why I can not read anything from Sitecore.

I have the following code

```cs
public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
{
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
  {
    var allowedDomain= //here I would like to read the domain from an item in 
                      //sitecore.
                    //BUT Context is always null here
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(allowedDomain, "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    //....other code
 }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Sitecore.Context` to read from an item in database.

You can use `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase(...).GetItem()` to get item and read its fields, e.g.

```cs
var settingsItem = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem("/sitecore/content/Settings");
var allowedDomains = settingsItem["Allowed Domains"];
```

And yes, it means that the database is hardcoded to either `master` or `web`.

But `initialize` pipeline is executed when Sitecore application starts - shouldn't you use a config file instead of getting that data from Sitecore item?

Comment: But then in the CD server it is web DB. Isn't is kind of a hardcoding. Plz correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You're right. It's hardcoded. In my opinion you should not keep any data needed in `initialize` pipeline on Sitecore items. Use config files instead. Just add another `<setting>` tag there.

Comment: The requirement is actually get it from sitecore. probably i will have to check  if master db is null , go for web db. what do you say?

Comment: I would say that database is not a good place. But if you really have to do this, always use `web`, even on CM.

Comment: You could also introduce a config setting that specifies which database to read from. This would remove the 'hard-coding' from your initialize pipeline and move your database selection to an role-specific config file.